# Async Loading of Hierachical Kendo Treeview using Angular

Tags: async-await, axios, angular8, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to load a hierarchical treeview from an external source, but I'm having difficulties loading the first node childs and most likey the inner childs aswell (but this I don't know yet..).

The data is loaded through axios, so the RxJS Observable methods won't work. I tried may different things but when I'm expanding the first node the spinner just keeps on spinning until eternity.

Some of the points that I have tried

- Tried to assign the parent node with the childeren
- Tried an async modifier
- Tried many different things with hasChilderen function

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

My code:

tree.component.html

```
<kendo-treeview [nodes]="locations | async" [textField]="['shortName']" kendoTreeViewExpandable
  [hasChildren]="hasChildren.bind(this)" [children]="fetchChildren.bind(this)">
</kendo-treeview>
```

tree.component.ts

```
export class TreeComponent implements OnInit {
  public locations: Promise<Location[]>

  constructor(private locationService: LocationService,
    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.locations = this.locationService.getBaseLocation();
  }

  public hasChildren = (item: Location): boolean => item.hasChildLocations;

  public fetchChildren = (item: Location): Promise<Location[]>  => this.locationService.getChildLocations(item.locationId);
}
```

location.service.ts

```
export class LocationService {
  async getBaseLocation(): Promise<Location[]> {
    return await axios.get<Location>('/Location/GetBaseLocation')
      .then((response: AxiosResponse<Location>) => {
        return [response.data];
      });
  }

  async getChildLocations(locationId: string): Promise<Location[]> {
    return await axios.get<Location[]>(`/Location/GetLocationTree?UpperLocationID=${locationId}`)
      .then((response: AxiosResponse<Location[]>) => response.data);
  }
}
```

location.model.ts

```
export interface Location {
    locationId: string;
    upperLocationId: string;
    locationTypeId: number;
    shortName: string;
    plantCode: string;
    hasChildLocations: boolean;

    icon: string;
    isSelected: boolean;

    childeren: Location[];
}
```

e.g. Spinner keeps rolling

[image: Visual fault]

console prints out an error before my childs are loaded from the external service, so my 5 cents are on the fact that angular is trying to expand the nodes before they are loaded.
[image: Console error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution:

Change

```
public fetchChildren = (item: any) this.locationService.getChildLocations(item.locationId);
```

to

```
  public fetchChildren = (item: any) => from(this.locationService.getChildLocations(item.locationId));
```